# Modifying Redis key TTL without triggering WATCH

Tags: redis

Is it possible to change a key's TTL without triggering any watches on the key. 
Possible via lua scripting ?

```
SET A 1
EXPIRE A 1
WATCH A
EXPIRE A 5  <--- this will trigger WATCH
MULTI
SET A 2
EXEC
```

Comment: No it is not possible. But with LUA you can implement transactions easily, can you describe your use case (with two clients, to check the race conditions)?

Comment: The use case was to extend a lock's duration while a transaction is happening.